# How to use googledrive::drive_upload() without changing the Google ID of file?

Tags: r, google-drive-api

When I upload a pptx file to Drive (or any file) I'd like to maintain the Google ID for the file, but every time I execute this function, a new Google ID is created even when `overwrite=TRUE`. This breaks the hyperlink that stakeholders were using to find the file in Drive. Is there a way to maintain the Google ID when overwriting during upload?

```
googldrive::drive_upload(
    my_pres,
    name = "My Presentation",
    type = 'presentation', # converts pptx to Googleslides
    overwrite = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [googledrive::drive_upload()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googledrive/versions/2.0.0/topics/drive_upload) wraps the [Files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) method of the Drive API. That is the wrong function to use for *updating* a file. The `overwrite` argument set as TRUE stands for:

> "[...] Check for a pre-existing file at the filepath. If there is zero or one, move a pre-existing file to the trash[...]"

You should use [googledrive::drive_update()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googledrive/versions/2.0.0/topics/drive_update) which wraps the [Files.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) method of the Drive API. From the R docs, is described as:

> "[...] Update an existing Drive file id with new content ("media" in Drive API-speak), new metadata, or both. To create a new file or update existing, depending on whether the Drive file already exists, see drive_put().  [...]"